# Get multiple row values using SqlDataReader in C#

Tags: c#

I am working with C# winform application.This is my code:

```
my_con.Open();
using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(" select Medicine_Name from stock where Medicine_Quantity<5", my_con))
 {
    SqlDataReader Reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    if (Reader2.HasRows)
    {
        String text1;
        Reader2.Read();
        while (Reader2.Read())
        {

           text1=Reader2["Medicine_Name"].ToString();

           lblwarn.Text = text1+" Medicines quantity is below 5 please order this medicines!!";
        }

    }
    Reader2.Close();
```

Using this code I am getting only one Medicine_Name which has  the Medicine_Quantity less then 5 shown in image but I want to show multiple Medicine_Names which has Medicine_Quantity less then 5.Please help!!

[image]

Comment: you are (re)setting the `text1` variable on each row, maybe you want to add to it? i.e. `text1+="\n" + Reader2["Medicine_Name"].ToString();`

Comment: Also please read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/jj839734.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply overwritting text1.

You want to append to it....something like.....

```
text1 = text1 + ", " + Reader2["Medicine_Name"].ToString();
```

But you'll need to tody it up for the bgining and end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your quake response it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on each turn of loop you erase the old value of text by the new one.

One solution would be to concatenate each sentences, like that:

```
my_con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(" select Medicine_Name from stock where Medicine_Quantity<5", my_con))
             {
                SqlDataReader Reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                if (Reader2.HasRows)
                {
                    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                    Reader2.Read();
                    while (Reader2.Read())
                    {
                        str.Append(String.Format("{0} medicines quantity is below 5 please order this medicines !\n", Reader2["Medicine_Name"].ToString()));
                    }
                    lblwarn.Text = str.ToString();

                }
                Reader2.Close();
```